# Unknown provider: $$isDocumentHiddenProvider angularJS

Tags: angularjs

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$isDocumentHiddenProvider <- $$isDocumentHidden <- $$animateQueue <- $animate <- $compile <- FileItem <- FileUploader <- $$animateQueue
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.14/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24isDocumentHidden…ompile%20%3C-%20FileItem%20%3C-%20FileUploader%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue
    at angular.js:68
    at angular.js:4381
    at Object.getService [as get] (angular.js:4529)
    at angular.js:4386
    at getService (angular.js:4529)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4561)
    at angular.js:4387
    at getService (angular.js:4529)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4561)
    at angular.js:4387
```

Lately I am getting this error in console. I checked the url which says:

> This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a
>   required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined
>   and spelled correctly. For example:

but problem is that we have more then 200 files. How to know in which file is error and where?

This error occurs after new environment installation ...

Comment: Can you show me your main.js code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having one or some modules that are using the different version than the angularjs core.

As mentioned in the error details, you are using `angularjs v1.4.14` but

`$$isDocumentHiddenProvider` is a private property, which is not introduced until `v1.6.x`.

See the source code at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.x/src/ng/document.js

So the solution is to make all angular related modules the same version as the angularjs core.